# Constantly stuck on logging in after latest Windows update

Tags: windows-10

Asking on behalf of my partner, whom I'm trying to troubleshoot for... after the latest automatic Windows update, his desktop Windows 10 installation gets constantly stuck at the login screen. Entering anything into the password field results in it "loading" for minutes or hours until we manually power it off.

Things we've tried:

- Entering BIOS so we can try loading in safe mode. We cannot enter BIOS. The usual key (del) does not work when booting up. Other common key combinations don't work either. I suspect it's because the keyboard isn't detected until Windows itself loads, at which point it's too late to enter BIOS
- Trying to access safe mode or a restore point in other ways. There doesn't seem to be that option from the Windows login screen

Is there anything else we can try without having to reinstall Windows entirely? (Which would hopefully be the last resort)

Answer (score 0):

Safe mode is not useful if you don't know what to do after that . Your best option to repair the startup is to access the Advanced Startup Options.

Open the Start menu and click on Settings. In Settings click on Update & Security, then click on Recovery (on the left). Below Advanced Startup click on Restart now button.

In Advanced Startup Options click on Troubleshoot, then click Advanced Options. First of all click on Startup Repair. If Startup Repair isn't successful click on System Restore: select the most recent restore point. If you have none or if system restore is unsuccessful then try Go back to the previous build.

In Startup Settings you can choose to boot in Safe Mode. If nothing works you have the choice to reset the computer (Reset this PC) keeping your files, but you will have to install again all programs. Good luck